# How to auto-reload (start) docker container with supervisor

Tags: mongodb, docker, supervisord

I'm stuck with a problem where I can't perfectly start my container via supervisor.
I have a mongodb container, which I want to run under supervisor.
Supervisor config itself:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

and mongodb container conf file:

```
[program:mongo]
command=/usr/bin/docker start b1b -DFOREGROUND
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
exitcodes=0
startsecs=0
```

When I do "supervisorctl restart mongo" it will start container, but after I stop it it will not relaunch it automatically.
Any advice on it?

Comment: Doesn't https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Docker already has the facility to restart stopped/failed containers, you do not need supervisor.

```
docker run --restart=always nginx
```